When testing a React component, how do I ensure my component renders via a url with params?
I have a component that can be hit through two flows. One route is user/Plan and the other is user/:userId/Plan. I have different parts of the component that render based on a value I get from calling useParams to see which flow we are going through. Is there a way I can render the component and ensure it uses the user/:userId/Plan flow?
I'm able to get the default tested just by doing the following:
        const result = render(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <UserPlan model={modelStub} />
            </BrowserRouter>,
        );

However, I'm not sure how I can force it to render with the url user/:userId/Plan? Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I just be mocking useParams or something?

I was able to get this working by utilizing <MemoryRouter>. My code:
const route = '/User/1/Plan';

const result = render(
   <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[route]}>
        <Routes>
            <Route path={UserRoutes.User.Plan} element={<UserPlan model={modelStub} />} />
        </Routes>
   </MemoryRouter>,
);
    

